# Invalid number of Directories on Batch

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I wanted to copy a few files into subdirectories inside a single directory. I'm using batch btw.

So far this is my code:

```
FOR /D %%A In ("C:/.../Desktop/exampledirectory/*") DO 
xcopy C:/.../Desktop/*.exe %%A
```

In the ... Areas are my personal details.
But when I run the batch file, nothing happens, and if I try it in open cmd (changing the % symbols) I says invalid number of directories, it lists out all of the subdirectories that I want to paste it in, but it just says invalid number of Directories.

I have searched for countless hours on the internet trying to find a solution for my problem.

Also after, the exampledirectory/ I did add a star, but you can't see it, and the it also applies to the .exe

Answer (score 1):

Ah - in all probability, the problem is with the infamous `...`

If these contain spaces or some other batch-sensitive characters, you'd need to enclose the entire file/directoryname in "quotes".

Please also not that `\` is a directory-separator; `/` is a switch-indicator.

```
FOR /D %%A In ("C:\...\Desktop\exampledirectory\*") DO xcopy "C:\...\Desktop\*.exe" "%%A"
```

should see you right - and all on one line, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%A In ("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\exampledirectory\*") DO (
    xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*.exe" "%%A"
)
```

Check alsoo Magoo's answer.
There are few problems:

1. I don't think the script will be able to find `C:\...\Desktop\`
   directory so maybe will be better to use `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\`
2. If you intend to use the `DO` block on a new line you need brackets
3. should use `\` instead of `/`